# How to query Windows Control Panel Programmatically?

Tags: c++, windows, search, mfc, controlpanel

I need to search the entire Windows Control Panel for a string (just like windows search from start menu or control panel explorer) in C++ MFC, anyone could help me?

I've already tried to search within the control panel virtual folder but doesn't work...

EDIT: It Works NOW! but only if compliled to the proper plataform (x86 or x64) (x86 dosen't work on x64 SO)

```
void CSearchView::BuildControlPanelCache()
{
    CComPtr<IShellFolder> pDesktop;
    SHGetDesktopFolder(&pDesktop);
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE path;
    SHGetKnownFolderIDList(FOLDERID_ControlPanelFolder,0,NULL,&path);
    CComPtr<IShellFolder> pFolder;
    pDesktop->BindToObject(path,NULL,IID_IShellFolder,(void**)&pFolder);

    ILFree(path);

    CComPtr<IEnumIDList> pEnum;
    if (pFolder->EnumObjects(NULL,SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS|SHCONTF_FOLDERS,&pEnum)!=S_OK) pEnum=NULL;
    if (!pEnum) return;

    PITEMID_CHILD pidl;
    while (pEnum->Next(1,&pidl,NULL)==S_OK)
    {
      STRRET strDispName;

        if( pFolder->GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, SHGDN_NORMAL, &strDispName) == S_OK )
        { 
              CComPtr<IQueryInfo> pLink;
              if (SUCCEEDED(pFolder->GetUIObjectOf(NULL,1,(PCITEMID_CHILD*) &pidl,IID_IQueryInfo,NULL,(void**)&pLink)))
              {
                    TCHAR *pwszTip; 
                    pLink->GetInfoTip( 0, &pwszTip ); 
                    if ( pwszTip ) 
                          { 
                                SHFree( pwszTip ); 
                          } 
                    //pLink->Release();           
              }
        }

        ILFree(pidl);
    }
}
```

It seems to do the trick! Ty Guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try searching `%SYSTEM%\*.cpl`.  On some systems, `%CSIDL_CONTROLS%\*.cpl`.

Comment: how would I serach for the applet name or description? load all .cpl one by one to verify if the name or description match?

Comment: That's one way.  Depending on your objectives, maybe you could `system("grep pattern %SYSTEM%/*.cpl");`?

Comment: Not all .cpl files are in %system%, people are supposed to register them in the registry these days...

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate all the control panel items and search for the one which you are looking for try [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232536) and [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?p=378869)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify. Target SO is Vista/7