# Getting the Windows Control Panel's virtual folder

Tags: winapi, com

Why would GetPath always return E_FAIL when querying FOLDERID_ControlPanelFolder? Other FOLDERIDs actually do work:

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
*path = '\0';
LPWSTR pwcPath = NULL;

CoInitialize(NULL);

IKnownFolderManager *pFolderManager = NULL;
if ((hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(KnownFolderManager), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IKnownFolderManager), (LPVOID *)&pFolderManager)) == S_OK)
{
    IKnownFolder *pControlPanelFolder = NULL;
    if ((hr = pFolderManager->GetFolder(FOLDERID_ControlPanelFolder, &pControlPanelFolder)) == S_OK)
    {
        hr = pControlPanelFolder->GetPath(0, &pwcPath);

        if (hr == S_OK && pwcPath)
        {
            int nSize = wcslen(pwcPath);
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pwcPath, nSize, path, nSize+2, NULL, NULL);
            path[nSize] = '\0';
            CoTaskMemFree(pwcPath);
        }

        pControlPanelFolder->Release();
        pControlPanelFolder = NULL;
    }

    pFolderManager->Release();
    pFolderManager = NULL;
}

CoUninitialize();
```

(Yes, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233812/how-to-query-windows-control-panel-programmatically) but I don't have need for all that enumeration stuff.)

Comment: Maybe because Control Panel is a _virtual_ folder, and as such it does not have an actual path?

Comment: [Getting PIDL of Control Panel](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/04c90891-641a-424d-b4a6-7208ba98d2d0/getting-pidl-of-control-panel): `string ControlPanelGUID = "::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Control Panel has no directory path because it does not exist on the disc. You can get its PIDL, and even a Desktop Absolute Parsing "display name" (via GetShellItem and GetDisplayName), but not a directory path.

Answer (score 1):

Reason why I needed the path was that I wanted to open the controp panel with a ShellExecute "open". I now execute the control panel program directly, with the benefit of being able to select the desired applet right away (in this case "Sound"). I hope it's not too pretentious that I post this as answer:

```
char controlpanelpath[2000];
UINT controlpanelpathbuffersize = sizeof(controlpanelpath);
int actualcontrolpanelpathsize;
if (actualcontrolpanelpathsize = GetSystemDirectory(controlpanelpath, controlpanelpathbuffersize))
{
    char *parameters = "\\control.exe mmsys.cpl,,0";
    if (actualcontrolpanelpathsize + strlen(parameters) < controlpanelpathbuffersize)
    {
        strcat(controlpanelpath, parameters);
        WinExec(controlpanelpath, SW_NORMAL);
    }
}
```

Comment: WinExec is a bit old-school, if you use ShellExecute you can just pass it `mmsys.cpl`